# error when importing packages

Tags: java, swing, identifier

```
package textar;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class textarea extends JInternalFrame
{
     public static JTextArea txtaMessage;
     textarea() {
         super("Private Cloud Environment",true,false,true,true);       
         txtaMessage=new JTextArea();
         JScrollPane  scrollPane=newJScrollPane(txtaMessage,
                                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
         txtaMessage.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
         txtaMessage.setEditable(false);
         getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
         getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
         setSize(650,650);
         setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

So above is my block of  code which has to b called in the followin program

```
import package textar.*;
public Main()
{                   
    //creating object for textarea InternalFrame
    textarea objtxta=new textarea();
    addFrame(objtxta);
}
```

but when compiling

```
  import package textar.*;
  ^
  1 error

  "error: identifier expected" pops out !!
```

I hav skipped other parts of d program because they have nothing to do with the package.

Help me out please !!
And Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the `package` keyword is invalid in `import` statement here. You can use:

```
import textar.*;
```

Your calling class does not appear to have the class declared:

```
import textar.*;

public class Main {

   public Main() {                   
    //creating object for textarea InternalFrame
    textarea objtxta=new textarea();
    addFrame(objtxta);
   }
   ...
```

Also there should be spaces between the keywords in the declaration of `JScrollPane` in the `textarea` class:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtaMessage,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Thanks .. but when i do that , i get this error "textar package dosenot exist"